# How can we perform 2 get request at same time Rest assured API Testing

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, cucumber, rest-assured

JAVA RESTASSURED APITESTNG CUCUMBER

when I send get request using path variable and query param, I get a token in the response body and I will not get proper response until I add that token as a query param and send another get request.

So How can I perform that?

**Given** Cucumber Feature File

- Given API has the following filed <"fieldName">
- When API sends a "GET" request to "TranscationAPI"
- Then API will receive the response code as 200
- And the body will have following field

Should I change it to something like this?

- Given API has the following filed <"fieldName">
- When API sends a "GET" request to "TranscationAPI"
- Then API will receive token as ""
- When API sends again "GET" request to "TranscationAPI"
- Then API will receive the response code as 200
- And the body will have following field

Or I can use handle this through a different method.

Answer (score 0):

Background is the great place to obtain token - see https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by Java multithreading mechanism - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm